# Set file permission fortran

Tags: file, fortran, runtime-error

I get this error:

```
forrtl: severe (9): permission to access file denied, unit 900, file C:\Abaqus_JOBS\mEFT.txt
```

When I try to open and simultaneously create the file `C:\Abaqus_JOBS\mEFT.txt`:

```
OPEN(900, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/mEFT.txt", action = "READWRITE", status = "UNKNOWN")
```

The error occurs and the file is not created. When the error occurs the file has already been created and deleted at least 100 times.

EDIT:
It seems the error is related to the fact that Windows don't delete or close the files immediately and in a parallel computation one could try to access the file when the file still exists... any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you explicitly set status to unknown? Why not replace?

Comment: sorry not being a dos guy, but shouldn't those be backslashes?

Comment: Backslashes do not matter.

Comment: @VladimirF: so should I use: `OPEN(900, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/mEFT.txt", action = "READWRITE")`? I use `status = "UNKNOWN"` to be general so to minimize the chance of getting errors

Comment: I would use `status = "replace"` in this case, but it depends on your intentions.

Comment: neither status would cause that error. Something is wrong with your path.  How old is your compiler?

Comment: @george: I don't compile it myself. This is done by another program which uses the .for file as an input. However, I've VS2010 installed with Intel Visual Fortran 2011, so maybe the software uses them (they are in fact a prerequisite). I thought it was related to file attributes but other files are generated in the manner and I get no error.